# Можно ли обойти 403?

Tags: php, http

Иногда папку защищают и если через браузер открыть то вылезит ошибочка 403, можно ли как то открыть эту страничку средствами php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если защита через .htaccess, то врятли, разве что там стоит исключение.

Comment: Спасибо, так и знал)

Comment: Удачи Вам!